# Spring IDE with Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I try to follow a tutorial that talks about Spring IDE with Hibernate.
I'm using the spring framework 3.2 and I create my own library contains all the jar framework and I have another library hibernate 4
I do the same examples, but I still have this message:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beanshttp://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="datasource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url"  value="jdbc:postgresql:T"/>
    <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="datasource" ref="datasource"/>**No setter found for property 'datasource' in class 
     'org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean'**
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
    <list>
    <value>com.model.Cours</value>
    <value>com.model.Student</value>
    </list>
    </property>


    </bean>
    </beans>
```

Why please? I'm stuck please the proposal if it is possible
is there probleme with annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean. I work with the hibernate4 
and it not exist hibernate4.annotation ...

Comment: I think you forgot to paste the message.

Comment: Do you have the PostGre Driver on your classpath?

Comment: this is the message editeur eclipse has shown :No setter found for property 'datasource' in class 
 'org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean'

Comment: Yes i have the driver ..but it is editor message and i do not running it yeet

Answer (score 1):

It's a typo, should be `<property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"/>` , not `<property name="datasource" ref="datasource"/>`

**name="dataSource"** not **name="datasource"**

Answer (score 0):

The "name" attribute of the "property" element denotes the member variable name of the referenced class org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource(http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html) where the member variable is declared as "protected DataSource dataSource". It is case sensitive. So the value of the "name" attribute must always match the case of the declared member variable name in the referenced class.